# Gradient of $X \mapsto \operatorname{Tr} \left( A (XAX)^{+} A \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $$f (X) := \operatorname{Tr} \left( A (XAX)^{+} A \right)$$ I would like to find the gradient $\nabla_X f$.

---

I am puzzled by this. I cannot find a closed form. Could someone please give me hints or help me out?

Comment: Could you give me a bit more hints?

Comment: This has a section on "derivatives of traces", and "derivatives of an inverse" that may help. 

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf

That pseudoinverse term looks nasty.

Comment: What does $+$ denote? The pseudoinverse?

Answer (score 0):

For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
M &= XAX, \qquad 
W &= M^+ \\
}$$
and their differentials
$\,\big\{$assuming $\;{\rm rank}(M+dM)={\rm rank}(M)\big\}$
$$\eqalign{
dM &= dX\:AX + XA\;dX \\
dW &= -W\:dM\:W+ \LR{I-WM}dM^TW^TW + WW^TdM^T\LR{I-MW} \\
dW^T &= -W^TdM^TW^T + W^TW\,dM\LR{I-WM} + \LR{I-MW}dM\:WW^T \\
}$$
and use a colon as a product notation for the trace function
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}\LR{A^TB} \\
}$$
Using the above notation, write the function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A^2:W^T \\
d\phi &= A^2:dW^T \\
 &= A^2:\LR{-W^TdM^TW^T+ W^TW\,dM\LR{I-WM} + \LR{I-MW}dM\:WW^T} \\
 &= \LR{-W^T\LR{A^2}^TW^T + W^TWA^2\LR{I-WM} + \LR{I-MW}A^2WW^T}:dM \\
 &\equiv \:\c{G}:dM \\
 &= \:G:\LR{dX\:AX + XA\;dX} \\
 &= \LR{GX^TA^T + A^TX^TG}:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &= \:GX^TA^T + A^TX^TG,
\qquad\qquad
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M} = G \\
\\
}$$

---

$\sf NB\!:\:$ The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a colon product to be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= B:\LR{A^TC} = A:\LR{CB^T} \\
}$$